# how to handle multiple error messages in my case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two error message strings, I would like to show them on UI seperately.

```
flash[:error] = "Error message one"
flash[:error] = "Error message two"
```

currently, they both flash for a while, and the second error message is hide by the first one.

I would like the "**error message one**" flash for seconds, and "**error message two**" is located below "**error message one**", and stay on the page without disappear. How to do this in rails 3?

Comment: try this gem https://github.com/dapi/gritter_notices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not limited to flash[:error]. You could for example define

```
flash[:second] = "Error message two"
```

and have this displayed in the main layout app/views/layout/application.html.erb with:

```
<section id="flash">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %>
</section>
```

This results in two divs one after the other and if you need to, you can implement a fade-out on the first one using Prototype or JQuery.

Comment: how to make the message stable on the page then? not flash and disappear I mean.

Comment: All flash messages are "stable" until the next request. Or do you mean to remain over multiple pages? Than you would either need to set the flash again or take another approach, for example to store this value in the session and displaying it in the main layout. Then it will remain until you clear the value from the session. And for flash you might be interested in flash.now and flash.keep methods.

Comment: Did you change the layout to display the flash and not just set the flash message?